# Django parsing values of fields in models - Extracting pk

Tags: python, html, django, parsing, model

I'm completely lost on part of my Django website. I finally figured out a way to have the same model create a template and then use that template and create another post. This works and is ideal. Now I need to put them in different locations on the screen so I basically need two for-loops and a way to decipher the two(templates and posts off of templates) apart from each other. The model has a title and a content field. When a template is created the title always starts with "Temp: ". I'm completely lost on this because I need to parse through the model and not just use an HTML parser because the content won't already be on the page and there is more than just the title that needs to be moved. I need a way I think in the views.py file to get the pk of ALL titles that start with "Temp: " and the content field tied with it and return it in a variable to the HTML file. I have been working on this for 3 days now and I just really need help.

views.py

```
def docpostlistview(request):
    field = DocPost.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'my_app/docpost_list.html', {'field': field})
```

HTML

```
<div class="blocks">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col">
        <a href="{% url 'doc-post-create-normal' %}" style="color: white; height: 10px; z-index: -6;">TESTESTESTESTESTESTESTES</a>
    </div>

    {% if user.Doc.all %}
        {% for post in user.Doc.all %}
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card card_template hoverable">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <a href="{% url 'use_template' pk=post.pk %}" style="color: black">
                            <p>
                                {{ post.content|safe }}
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <p>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                        <div class="bottom_text">
                            {{ post.title }}
                            <div class="bottom_button">
                                <form action="{% url 'use_template' pk=post.pk %}" method="POST">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <a style="background-color: #2f3d50; border-radius: 18px; height: 30px; position: relative; top: 5px;" href="{% url 'use_template' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary"><div style="position: relative; top: -3px;">Create</div></a><!--use_template pk=post.pk   -   post-list-->
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="dots_img"> <img src="{% static 'threedots.png' %}" alt=""</a>
                            <ul>
                                <div class="edit_drop">
                                    <form action="{% url 'doc-post-update' pk=post.pk %}" method="POST">
                                        {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <a style="background-color: #2f3d50; border-radius: 18px;" href="{% url 'doc-post-update' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">EDIT</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                                <div class="delete_drop">
                                    <a style="background-color: #2f3d50; border-radius: 18px;" href="{% url 'delete_post' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                    <!--<form action="{% url 'reset' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                    </form>-->
                                </div>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <hr class="hline">
    {% else %}
        <div class="no_template">
            <p>Your new templates will appear here!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="no_post">
            <p>Your new documents will appear here!</p>
        </div>
        <hr class="hline-non">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="blocks2">
<div class="row">
```

Comment: Could you at least share the (simplified version) code of your model, views, html, etc.? Then the community would better understand it. For your reference, see this other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462364/not-null-constraint-failed-knb-balance-user-id-django

Comment: They are added sorry about that @Neil Godfrey Poncaino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) which utilizes the SQL `WHERE` clause.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#startswith
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups

Sample:

```
doc_posts = DocPost.objects.filter(title__startswith="Temp: ")
```

Here, `doc_posts` is an iterable `QuerySet` object containing a sequence of `DocPost` objects where each item's title starts with "Temp: ".

If all you want are the `id` and the `content` fields, you may use `values()`.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#values

Sample:

```
id_content_seq = DocPost.objects.filter(title__startswith="Temp: ").values("id", "content")
```

Here, `id_content_seq` is an iterable `QuerySet` object containing a sequence of `dict` objects containing `id` and `content` as keys for all items where the title starts with "Temp: ".

Comment: Works beautifully thanks! If anyone else is reading this and needs to display something like this and other data from the same model you first have to have DocPost.objects.all() then this then return them with context and context name such asdocs = DocPost.objects.all()
    context = {"docs": docs}

    context['templates'] = DocPost.objects.filter(title__startswith="Temp: ") then return context